# How to destroy instantiated button upon collision exit - Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, button, destroy

I am a beginner in Unity and I am currently making a simple game. I have a problem where the instantiated Button is not destroyed.

The process of the script is to instantiate a button and destroy it upon collision exit. But when I move out of the object, the object stays and it is not destroyed. i don't know if there is something wrong with the Destroy code of line.

Here is the script for the collision:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class InteractButtonPosition : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Button UI;
    private Button uiUse;
    private Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0);
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //uiUse = Instantiate(UI, FindObjectOfType<Canvas>().transform).GetComponent<Button>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //uiUse.transform.position = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(this.transform.position + offset);
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo)
    {
        if(collisionInfo.collider.name == "Player")
        {
            uiUse = Instantiate(UI, FindObjectOfType<Canvas>().transform).GetComponent<Button>();
            uiUse.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            uiUse.transform.position = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(this.transform.position + offset);
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit(Collision collisionInfo)
    {
        if(collisionInfo.collider.name == "Player")
        {
            Destroy(uiUse);
        }
    }
        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code does exactly what you have written, which is destroying `uiUse` which is a **Button** component. If you go and inspect your game object in the scene, you will see, that indeed, the button component has been destroyed.

What you want to do is to destroy the **GameObject** the button component is attached to, like: `Destroy(uiUse.gameObject)`

Comment: Another question, when I collide with the button that's been instantiated it sticks with my character when I try to walk around it (still colliding). It should just been on top of the object not moving or sticking with my character. What do I do?

Comment: Maybe it sticks with a character, as it is his child? No idea, frankly, I'm struggling to depict what your code is doing.